# Automatic exporting of dependencies in InteliJ Idea when reading poms?

Tags: maven, export, intellij-idea

i tried to search both here and on jetbranis.net however i did not found an answer.

I have created a project (*P*) using maven that have to modules (*A*,*B*). The module *A* is dependant on module *B* and module *B* is dependent on libraries *R*. When I open *P* using the InteliJ Idea 10.0.1 everything works smoothly. The only problem that i have is dependency handling.

The dependencies were imported transitively. Both *A*,*B* are now dependent on libraries *R*. I would expect *B* to be dependent on *R*, but i would expect *R* to be exported and *A* to be dependent only on *B*.

I found some old posts on  jetbrains that seam to be related, however it seams that they have opposite problem  http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/286098. Can anybody advise me please? Did i missed some configuration option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Maven's dependencies work; each module (aka Maven Project) has an isolated classpath. Dependencies, imported into IDEA, are not 'exported' to prevent interference between transitive dependencies.